# How quickly is the log file growing?

Tags: logging, tail

I use `tail -f logfile' to view the log in real time. I also need to know how many lines are appended to the logfile per second. Is there a command to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'wc -l logfile' to see linecount. Do it in loop to watch it in real time.
This one works at least in bash:

```
while true; do wc -l logfile; sleep 1; done
```

Comment: While this will work, it is very resource intensive, particularly on a logfile which you expect to grow very quickly.  It is also inaccurate as it greps the logfile and then waits 1 second.  The time spent grepping the logfile is thus additional to the sleep time, and very significant.

Comment: My log file was very large. wc -l would take a few seconds to finish. So I prefer not to read the entire file each time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a simple, built in way to see how many lines are appended a second, but depending on the problem you are trying to solve there may be some options -

1. If you just want a very rough indication, you could work out the average length of
    a line, and then monitor the size of the file, and do some basic maths for a rough
    indication.
2. Depending on what creates the log file, you should be able to redirect the log output
    to a script which counts the lines received before passing it through to a file it
    writes.   I can't advise on writing this script unless I know more about the use
    case, particularly how the log file is created, and what syslog program you are 
    using.